# Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired? + Spring security + CSRF

Tags: spring-security, csrf-protection

I am trying to implement CSRF via spring security.

But, facing **following error** in browser, after clicking login button(from home.jsp)

**"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?"**

I have following configuration in

spring-security-config.xml:

```
<http auto-config="false">
<csrf/>
</http>
```

home.jsp:

```
<form action="j_spring_security_check" id="LoginForm" method="post">       
    <input type="text" title="Username" name="j_username" id="j_username" 
           class="inset-shadow defaultText" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" title="Password" name="j_password" 
           id="j_password" class="inset-shadow defaultText" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" title="LOGIN" 
           onsubmit="javascript:{loginSubmit();}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="dc7ce2be-f73b-4086-8f90-8ef00b8f81d5"/>    
</form>
```

Error from jboss server.log:

```
2015-09-14 19:56:10,221 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/].[jsp]] (http-127.0.0.1-8190-2) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1024) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:110) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:99)
```

**Note : Not sure whether the error from server.log relates to CSRF**

Any help on this problem is highly appreciated?

Comment: I see someone thumbs down fro this question without an explanation. I am giving thumbs up, until I get an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="dc7ce2be-f73b-4086-8f90-8ef00b8f81d5"/>
```

did you try

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

As per the docs, the csrf and token would be computed by Spring and appended as a request parameter, with name as `${_csrf.parameterName}` and value as `${_csrf.token}`.

Comment: I did this already and I used exactly as what you suggested and "_csrf" is nothing but interpretation of ${_csrf.parameterName} and dc7ce2be-f73b-4086-8f90-8ef00b8f81d5 is interpretation of ${_csrf.token}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

I my case, the html page containing the form have a link tag to a css file into my web application.
This link to css file has been also protected by spring security and due to this, I had your error.

When I unprotect link to css file, no error occur.

This is an example how to unprotect files in Spring Security with Java Config

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
}
```